# Regex: Check if character exists in string and adjust rules accordingly

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing a regex to try and filter out invalid urls. This should be simple enough - a million examples are available online, I ended up using this one: `((https?|ftp|file)://)[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]+[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]`.

However, our specific requirements state that the url must end in either "?" or "&". This should also be fairly simple, it can be done by adding `(\\?|\\&)` to the end of the regex.

However, the requirements are further complicated by the following: **if "?" is already present in the string, then the url must end in & and *vice versa* "with the main items in the preceding statement the other way around."**

It should be noted that the regex written above and the general context of this question is within the javascript specifications.

### Edit per the request of commenter

Examples of input urls:

No "?" or "&" at all:

`https://helloworld.io/foobar` returns `false`

No "?" or "&" at end:

`https://helloworld.io/foo&bar` returns `false`

`https://helloworld.io/foo?bar` returns `false`

Single special character sound at end:

`https://helloworld.io/foobar?` returns `true`

`https://helloworld.io/foobar&` returns `true`

Alternating special characters in url:

`https://helloworld.io/foo&bar?` returns `true`

`https://helloworld.io/foo?bar&` returns `true`

Alternating special characters in url without unique ending:

`https://helloworld.io/foo&bar?baz&` returns `false`

`https://helloworld.io/foo?bar&baz?` returns `false`

Repeated special character found at end:

`https://helloworld.io/foo?bar?` returns `false`

`https://helloworld.io/foo&bar&` returns `false`

Alternating special characters with no special character at end:

`https://helloworld.io/foo&bar?baz` returns `false`

`https://helloworld.io/foo?bar?baz` returns `false`

### Second edit in response to another comment:

With this regex most of my problems are solved:

`((https?|ftp|file):\/\/)[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]+[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_|](\\?|\\&)`

However, I can not test for cases such as this:

`https://helloworld.io/foo&bar?baz?bum&`

This evaluates as valid, however, given that "&" is present in the string before the last char - it can not end with "&".

Comment: If a URL contains `&` then it cannot end with `?`

Comment: This is true, however, given our specific use case this requirement does not hold. We are filtering the urls to ensure they are ready for us to parse and customize. @anubhava

Comment: can you share sample strings that should and that shouldn't be matched? (including borderline cases)

Comment: Per your request I have added some examples to the question. @lemon

Comment: Please share your regexp + examples using https://regex101.com/ and mention the inputs that don't work, specifically

Comment: "Should be simple enough" -- I don't believe this statement is true.  I would not recommend using regex to parse URLs -- I would suggest a 3rd party library that has been well tested.

Comment: Do you really need all that in a single regex? You could use a second regex (`^([^?]*\?|[^&]*&)$`) or dedicated logic (`.endsWith()` and `.includes()`).

Comment: I have included an edit in response to your comment - the specific example was tested with the site you shared. @miraculixx

Comment: I am operating under technical requirements that are not ideal. If i could write a function for this there would be no need for the SO question. @Ouroborus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
(https|ftp|file):\/\/[^\/]+\/\w+((\?[^&\s]+)?&|(&[^\?\s]+)?\?)(\s|$)
```

Explanation:

- `(https|ftp|file)`: prefix
- `:\/\/`: colon and double slash
- `[^\\]+`: anything other than next slash
- `\/`: slash
- `\w+`: any alphanumeric character

Then there are two options.

Option 1: `(\?[^&\s]+)?&`:

- `(\?[^&\s]+)?`: optional ? followed by any character other than &
- `&`: &

Option 2: `(&[^\?\s]+)?\?)`:

- `(&[^\?\s]+)?`: optional & followed by any character other than ?
- `\?`: ?

Ending up with:
*`(\s|$)`: space or endstring symbol

These will match the examples you provided. For more refinements, point to new examples.

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/c3e3jS/1).

Comment: For some reason I didn't get alerted when you answered - your regex is awesome! It still has a small false positive problem with urls that fit the following pattern: `https://helloworld.io/foo&bar?baz?bum&` but that is something i can work on. Thank you!

Comment: Actually I changed my initial regex to match it, because it didn't match before. Let me do a rollback.

Comment: Very minor edit to your final solution: adding `($|\s)` to the end makes it perfect! (entire string should be evaluated) @lemon

Answer (score 2):

Working from your initial regex:

`((https?|ftp|file)://)[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]+[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]`

Then modifying it for each case:

`((https?|ftp|file)://)[-A-Za-z0-9+@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]+[-A-Za-z0-9+@#/%=~_|]&`

and

`((https?|ftp|file)://)[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]+[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]\?`

Then joining them and de-duplicating the common prefix:

`((https?|ftp|file)://)([-A-Za-z0-9+@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]+[-A-Za-z0-9+@#/%=~_|]&|[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]+[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]\?)`

Adding `^`, `$`, and the correct escaping for javascript, this would be:

`^((https?|ftp|file):\/\/)([-A-Za-z0-9+@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]+[-A-Za-z0-9+@#\/%=~_|]&|[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]+[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]\?)$`

[Tests over on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/IUqx7D/4)

Comment: So far tests are failing but I really like the idea you are going with by stringing together the or statements ... I'm going to play around with that and if i can crack this nut with your help ill upvote you anyways since I know this one was a pain. @Ouroborus

Comment: There's a particular edge case that isn't covered in your examples where a string ends in one character and contains multiple of the other character as in `https://helloworld.io/foo?bar?baz&`. This solution would return true for those but I'm not sure if that's your intent.

Comment: That is my intent (that they return true) - thank you for double checking